# RuntimeError: No ffmpeg exe could be found - FFMpeg error in Windows 10

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to run

```
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip
```

However I am continuously getting the followng error :

```
RuntimeError: No ffmpeg exe could be found. Install ffmpeg on your system, or set the IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE environment variable.
```

I have installed ffmpeg in my system and have added it in path. Also in cmd,

```
ffmpeg
```

gives proper output.

So anything I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: What does `echo $IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE` show?

Comment: $IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE

Comment: You might be running windows? Try `echo %IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE%`

Comment: %IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE%

Comment: So looks like it's not set, hence the error. If you're running Windows, there is an interface to change environment variables, type `env` in the start menu search to pull it up.

Comment: Yes what to write in Environment variables ?

Comment: yes please tell me

Answer (score 14):

try this before importing moviepy:

```
import os
os.environ["IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE"] = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg"
```